# Open new Cygwin window with executing alias from current window

Tags: bash, cygwin

I need to start new Cygwin window with running alias in it.
Opening new window is:

```
cygstart /bin/bash -li
```

*(Thanks to: [Spawn New Cygwin Window from Within Cygwin](https://superuser.com/questions/156309/spawn-new-cygwin-window-from-within-cygwin))*

But how can I send alias in that new Cygwin window? (alias compile="./ant compile")

```
cygstart /bin/bash -li ./ant compile
```

Current statement open new bash window and run command there, but not in new cygwin window.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know is old but the answer is:

```
cygstart --directory=${pwd} /bin/bash -li -c \"./ant compile\"
```

The escaped quotations mark are needed to pass the command to bash.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-c` switch to pass commands for bash to run, like so:

```
cygstart /bin/bash -li -c ./ant compile
```